# Undefined variable, scoping issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of an object in an array in React using Immutability Helpers.

```
  handleChange = (itemInput, itemNum = null) => event => {
    this.setState({
      rows: update(this.state.rows, {
        itemNum: {[itemInput]: {$set: event.target.value}},
      })
    });
  }
```

I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined". The reason is itemNum is undefined and I can't figure out why(I know it is undefined since if I replace it with 1, for example, the code works.
This is probably some scope issue :/ Thanks for any suggestions on how to fix that!

Just to clarify that the variables are all defined and I can console.log them before the `this.setState`.

`update` comes from https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html . I used the example under "Nested collections" where they have hardcoded the value 2, and in my case, it has to be `itemNum`

Basically, what I am trying to do is

```
this.state.rows[itemNum][itemInput] = event.target.value
```

but I guess React makes it a bit complicated for me...

In the constructor I have

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

And I call the onChange with `onChange={this.handleChange("searchType", i)}`

Comment: Why you have used currying concept here ? `() => () =>`

Comment: What is update?

Comment: Can you show the update function?

Comment: update comes from 'import update from 'react-addons-update';" which is React's Immutability Helper

Comment: Do you mind sharing whole class ?

Comment: As per documentation itemNum has to be index and itemInput has to be array, just wanna look on that part

Comment: @Garry, itemInput is the name of the attribute I want to change in element itemNum in the array this.state.rows

Comment: How do you subscribe to onChange event?

Comment: @Valerii just included it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleChange = (itemInput, itemNum = null) => event => {
    this.setState({
        rows: update(this.state.rows, {
            [itemNum]: {[itemInput]: {$set: event.target.value}},
        })
    });
};
```